# Is there a simple way to make a custom border shape for an HTML <div>?

Tags: html, css, border

I am building a webpage with cards arranged in a grid.

However, I would like my cards to have a unique shape, rather than just being rectangles. The shape I would like them to be is the shape of a manilla folder (pictured below)

Is there any relatively simply way to make a div with this shape?

[image: folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start using only html and css:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div .slant {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 -14px -4px;
  width: 40px;
}

div .slant::before,
main {
  border: 0.2em solid #000;
  background: #000;
}

div .slant::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0.5em;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #000;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

div.left .slant {
  padding: 1.5em 2em 1em 1em;
}

div.left .slant::before {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

main {
  display: block;
  margin: -8px 0 30px -14px;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div class="slant"></div>
</div>
<main>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me about 10 minutes just to do that, so if you have the motivation to improve it, feel free to do so. It is possible to do it with `divs` and positioning with CSS. It's just a matter of playing with z-index and shapes, but unless you just wan't to impress yourself for achieving it, the easiest way is to create a background image and move your html content over it.

I am not the best front-end programmer either so don't be arshe! I'm sure someone else could improve it even better with outline borders and stuff.

```css
div#panel {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div#box {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid red;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 48.5%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: ;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 47%;
  left: 46.9%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="panel"></div>
<div id="box">
  <p style="padding-left: 5px;"> Some text here</p>
</div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this shape as the background-image of the card. Remove the card default property like background-color, box-shadow...

HTML:

```
<div class="main-class">
    <div class="card">
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .main-class .card{
        background-image: url("path");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: transparent;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```